# Exceeded Google Maps API request quota

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Since the last Google Maps API Change i constantly get this message:

```
You have exceeded your request quota for this API
```

When i look in the Statistics there is a very small usage of API requests:

[image]

I don't send to many or too much requests, so whats going on here??

Comment: Did you enable billing account for your project? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage-and-billing

Comment: Have you enabled billing with a credit card?  From https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/ : As of June 11, 2018, you must enable billing with a credit card and have a valid API key for all of your projects.

Comment: It's only for local development...

Comment: That doesn't change the terms of use

Comment: OK, Thanks. Too bad, but entering credit card data for testing on localhost is too much for me.